# How to leave an internship for another internship?

Tags: communication, internship, resignation, quitting

I currently hold an unpaid internship. Most of the work I've been doing is not really related to my major or related to my immediate career goals. The people are nice, but I am bored most of the time. Recently I got hired at another internship that is paid, related to my major, and will be good experience to add to my resume. I am sure you can see why I want to leave.

Everyone at my current internship is relatively relaxed. The end date of my internship was always up to me. I initially told them I want to be there until mid august (didn't actually give them a date). Now I told the new internship I want to start next week. How do I graciously tell my current internship that I want to end earlier than I initially thought and that the upcoming week will be my last week there?

I was thinking of making an excuse about how my summer classes are a lot more time consuming than I thought and that I no longer have time to drive out here and intern. The internship is very time consuming as it is a 45 minute drive from my college and I'm usually here for 5 hours, then the drive back.

Answer (score 9):

Why prevaricate. Just tell them the truth, that you've found another internship which is more inline with your career goals, and thank them for the opportunity.

Comment: +1 Brief and to the point.  Just how I like my answers.

Answer (score 1):

Yea I suspect that you are over thinking this.  A good lesson to remember going forward is to just go and talk to your boss.  There are so many questions that I see where the answer is just talk to your boss.  Since  you never established a formal end date he may not even question why you are looking to end it now.
Good luck at the new place.

Answer (score 1):

Your current internship ends in the middle of August. Your new internship starts at the end of the first week of August. We're talking about a one-week discrepancy. Not the end of the world.

You have several options:

1. Ask the people of your second internship to start you in the second week of August.
2. Tell the people at your first internship that you have the second internship lined up, but that they want you to start at the end of the first week of August.

Either way, the people at your first internship have to know when your last day is, and the people at your second internship have to know when your first day with them is.

Answer (score 0):

> I currently hold an unpaid internship. Most of the work I've been
>   doing is not really related to my major or related to my immediate
>   career goals. The people are nice, but I am bored most of the time.
>   Recently I got hired at another internship that is paid, related to my
>   major, and will be good experience to add to my resume. I am sure you
>   can see why I want to leave.

Yes, please leave

> Everyone at my current internship is relatively relaxed. The end date
>   of my internship was always up to me. I initially told them I want to
>   be there until mid august (didn't actually give them a date). Now I
>   told the new internship I want to start next week. How do I graciously
>   tell my current internship that I want to end earlier than I initially
>   thought and that the upcoming week will be my last week there?

Send a friendly email. Thank them for giving you the opportunity to intern with them. Say you received another opportunity that more closely aligns with your career goals. Mention this isn't a goodbye, but really a hello, and hope you cross paths with them in future.

> I was thinking of making an excuse about how my summer classes are a
>   lot more time consuming than I thought and that I no longer have time
>   to drive out here and intern. The internship is very time consuming as
>   it is a 45 minute drive from my college and I'm usually here for 5
>   hours, then the drive back.

No need for that. A sweet email will be fine. Who knows, maybe they will take you out to lunch on your last day!